# Datagridview pagination in C# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, pagination

Hai guys,

- Can we implement default pagination
  like asp:gridview for a datagridview
  in a c# windows application?
- Any samples to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is a very frequently asked question. Just look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridView_manipulation.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/TPeplow/archive/2009/07/14/datagridview-paging-using-virtual-mode.aspx).

Comment: second link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Button as Last , First, Prev , Next
2. Implement the page function

Next( less than total increase current page position , And reload
    data source )

Prev ( more than 1 decrease current page position and reload data source ) .. and so on

1. Write two SQLs for the following :

   1. get row counts of your search query
   2. get query result with no. of rows skipped and limit (no. of records per page)

Remarks: try to find any functions for SQL such as limit , offset to skip the rows

Most of the tutorials use SQL : select top  N ..where not in ( select top b*N ) ...
where N is the no. of records per page , b is the offset parameters ( current page - 1 ) to skip result rows.

Beware the performance issues occured when querying the large result.